# Java BufferedWriter does not close underlying writer

Tags: java

I am using a BufferedWriter to write in a File. All the nested streams of the BufferedWriter (FileOutputStream, GzipOutputStream, OuputStreamWriter, ...) should be automatically closed if I close the BufferedWriter. If all of the streams have been instantiated then closing only the outermost is just fine.

The documentation on Closeable interface states that close method:

> Closes this stream and releases any system resources associated with
> it.

So, I am wondering why I cannot find a `out.close();` in the source code of the java.io.BufferedWriter :

```
// Java 11.0.12_7 source code. Line 262
public void close() throws IOException {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (out == null) {
                return;
            }
            try (Writer w = out) {
                flushBuffer();
                // Why don't we have a out.close() here ?
            } finally {
                out = null;
                cb = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

How the out Writer is it closed ?

Comment: `try (Writer w = out) {`: that's a try-with-resources. There's an implicit call to `close()`

Comment: Up-voting @ernest_k's comment x1000!

Comment: @ernest_k Of course ! I m ashamed to have asked this question. It was obvious, I missed it :-(

Comment: Nice usefull trick using try-with-resources.